# Sylius product index get actual taxon

Tags: sylius

I need to get the actual taxon on my product listing in twig in front (route `sylius_shop_product_index`)

I only found this technique to do that

`{% set taxon = products.definition.driverConfiguration.repository.arguments.taxon %}`

But I odnt think is correct

do you have another method ?

I'm on sylius 1.8.11

Symfony 4.4.21

php 7.4.8

Comment: Hi, this is neither wrong nor bad. Other solutions would require getting the taxon from the repository again using the slug and locale from request.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing your very same issue, and in the end I see your suggestion as the only "correct" way, since that is the real taxon which is used by the resource bundle. Of course, this is a weak  constraint as someone could change the query without knowing the implication.

So, best solution to me:

`{% set taxon = products.definition.driverConfiguration.repository.arguments.taxon %}`

The real limit here is that the Resource bundle doesn't allow for the definition of views parameters or, IMO better, automatically expose the repository argument as a Twig Context by default.

The only alternative approach I found to this, is to define a TwigExtension named `SlugExtension` which defines a method `findTaxonBySlug`; with this you may retrive the proper taxon by using the current context, which is Channel, Locale and Slug. But it would be a waste of time, right now.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative @giosh94mhz mentioned will look like this:

**Twig Extension**

```php
namespace App\Twig;

use Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Repository\TaxonRepositoryInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\TaxonInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

final class TaxonExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private TaxonRepositoryInterface $taxonRepository;

    public function __construct(TaxonRepositoryInterface $taxonRepository)
    {
        $this->taxonRepository = $taxonRepository;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_taxon_by_slug', [$this, 'getTaxonBySlug']),
        ];
    }

    public function getTaxonBySlug(string $slug, string $locale): ?TaxonInterface
    {
        return $this->taxonRepository->findOneBySlug($slug, $locale);
    }
}
```

**Twig Template**

```
{% set taxon = get_taxon_by_slug(app.request.attributes.get('slug'), sylius.localeCode) %}
```

*IMO it's not worth unless you can reuse it for other purposes.*

Comment: exactly! My previous code looked exactly like this, but unfortunately I removed it before replying. Thanks for sharing, though.